# Add subtitle font in Kodi

Tags: subtitles, kodi, osmc, libreelec

I don't like the available subtitle fonts in Kodi and want to add my own `.ttf` file.

How do you do that? I use both OSMC and LibreELEC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSMC copy your `.ttf` font file to `/usr/share/kodi/media/Fonts/`. On LibreELEC the path is instead `/storage/.kodi/media/Fonts`. For this you need to activate SSH login, and use a tool like WinSCP to perform the copy.

This should suffice to make your font show up among the available Kodi subtitle fonts in the Kodi user interface.